# Why is this jQuery autocomplete not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following in my page header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/autoSuggest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/suggest.js"></script>
```

suggest.js is made of:

```
$(function(){

$("#idName input").autoSuggest("../Test.php", {minChars: 2, matchCase: true});
});
```

and autoSuggest.js is a plugin by Drew Wilson (http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)

Test.php is

```
<?php
include('database_info.inc');
$input = $_POST["idName"];
$data = array();
var_dump($data);
// query database to see which entries match the input
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE title LIKE '%$input%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$json = array();
$json['value'] = $row['id'];
$json['name'] = $row['title'];
$data[] = $json;
}
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

My var_dump() doesn't do anything and no items are suggested ...what could I be doing wrong? seems like there's no communication with Test.php

Comment: Have you looked at it with Firebug or Developer Tools to see if the request is being performed? Also, that's a big fat juicy SQL injection waiting to happen.

Comment: what is an HTML injection waiting to happen?...the fact that $input isn't cleaned up?...if so i only left it that way for the purposes of this question...thanks!

Comment: What about `.autoSuggest("Test.php"`

Comment: SQL injection, not HTML injection. brain fart, sorry. Yes, that's the issue I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the plug-in suggests it expects a parameter called `q` passed as a GET string, not as a POST.

```
<?
    $input = $_GET["q"];
    $data = array();
    // query your DataBase here looking for a match to $input
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field LIKE '%$input%'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $json = array();
    $json['value'] = $row['id'];
    $json['name'] = $row['username'];
    $json['image'] = $row['user_photo'];
    $data[] = $json;
    }
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Look a little further down for the `queryParam` option.

Comment: @mu: Yes, I see it *can* be configured thus, but there's no suggestion that it *is* in the OP's instantiation code. Furthermore, I think it still expects a GET query parameter, and not a POST.

Comment: It was just a suggestion to make a better answer, not a criticism.